# Check if array contains a string in iOS

Tags: ios, arrays

My array is having the data below. I want to search whether email id and password text fields are matched with the array values or not. If they are matched, then user can login else invalid credentials message is alerted. Please help me.

```
    2014-01-03 12:08:20.909 Appify[542:11303] (
    {
        EmailId="sarika@gmail.com";password=sarika;
    },
    {
        EmailId="kalyan@gmail.com";password=kalyan;
    },
    {
        EmailId="kalyan@gmail.com";password=kalyan;
    }
    )
```

Comment: Don't post code in comments. Edit the original question to include your *properly formatted* code.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I think the user is new, updated the question from taking comment

Comment: Of course he is new. He should still pay attention to the proper way to use the website.  Thousands of "new" users get it right every day.

Comment: ThanQ @JonathonReinhart yes am the new user

Answer (score 1):

```
try iterating through your array and find if username and password matches with the textfield data

For( NSDictionary *data in myArray)
{

    if([emailtextField.text isEqualtoString:[data objectForKey:@"EmailId"]] &&  [passwordtextField.text isEqualtoString:[data objectForKey:@"password"]]){

       //Login
      break;

   }
   else{
       // Not Logged in
   }

}
```

Comment: Am getting this error, please solveTerminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString isEqualtoString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1dfa844'

Comment: check if condition, weather [data objectForkey:@"Email"] or [data objectForkey:@"password"]  returns any value or not.

Comment: yes its returning the values contains in array

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dict setValue:emailTextField.text forKey:@"email"];
[dict setValue:passwordTextField.text forKey:@"password"];
if([myarray containsObject:dict]){
        //login
 }else{
        //dont login
    }
```

Comment: 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSDictionaryI 0x717a040> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key email.'

Comment: please check your xib file in the connections inspector and see if there is a referencing outlet with an exclamation mark(!) at the right

Comment: all connections are fine

Comment: I have seen this error a lot of time and this one arises when you had an IBOutlet connected and later you delete or edit the variable, but the xib file is still referencing the old variable. have you tried cleaning the project?

Answer (score 0):

```
Appify[542:11303] (
{
    EmailId="sarika@gmail.com";password=sarika;
},

{
    EmailId="kalyan@gmail.com";password=kalyan;
},

{
    EmailId="kalyan@gmail.com";password=kalyan;
}

)
```

Password is not nsstring type, actualy your data :

```
Appify[542:11303] (

{
    EmailId="sarika@gmail.com";password="sarika";
},

{
    EmailId="kalyan@gmail.com";password="kalyan";
},

{
    EmailId="kalyan@gmail.com";password="kalyan";
}

)
```

Check your data